# Trying to learn Azure but sample project fails. How to get it to build/run?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I am trying to run the PhluffyFotos sample project located here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PhluffyFotos-Sample-7ecffd31?SRC=VSIDE

- I have downloaded it from that link
- I have also tried opening from  File|New|Project|Online|Samples|Visual c#|Cloud|Microsoft Azure in order to load the sample.
- I installed VS 2012 Pro, SQL Server Express and the Azure SDK 1.7 as specified but I get a null error when I run it (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime is where the error is but I can't find the PDB file to get source info) and also errors on a state file and on a package config.
- I upgraded the Azure SDK to 2.5 but same errors. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.5\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll is listed in the worker's references.
- I uninstalled all that and tried it on VS2013 with LocalDB and Azure SDK 2.5 and got the same errors.
- I tried it with VS2013, SQL Server Express and Azure SDK 2.5 and get the same errors. These are the errors:

  ```
  Warning 1   Could not read state file "obj\Debug\PhluffyFotos.Data.WindowsAzure.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache". Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    PhluffyFotos.Data.WindowsAzure

  Warning 2   Could not read state file "obj\Debug\PhluffyFotos.Worker.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache". Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   PhluffyFotos.Worker

  Error   3   Failed to download package correctly. The contents of the package could not be verified.    PhluffyFotos.Web

  Error   4   The command ""c:\users\me\documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PhluffyFotos Sample1\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "c:\users\me\documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PhluffyFotos Sample1\PhluffyFotos.Web\packages.config" -source "" -o "c:\users\me\documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PhluffyFotos Sample1\packages"" exited with code 1.   PhluffyFotos.Web
  ```

This is supposed to run locally as is and run on Azure after having the connection strings set to services created there. I cannot get it to run locally. How can I make this sample happy and get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try, running VS as administrator
Do a clean on your solution
Rebuild again

**Update**

Ok i downloaded the project, there are several other things that would be going wrong

- Right click on the solution and click "manage nuget packages for solution"
- Restore any missing packages, if there are missing packages there is usually a yellow bar at the top stating the problem with a restore button
- you'll have to change your Web.Config file in the web project, find the following

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <connectionStrings>
>      <add name="DataConnectionString" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={YOUR-ACCOUNT};AccountKey={YOUR-ACCOUNT-KEY}" />
> ```

- Update YOUR-ACCOUNT and {YOUR-ACCOUNT-KEY}, with azure storage account information you get from azure portal

Comment: That got rid of the warnings. I was already running as administrator but the clean helped some. I still have the null and the package problems, though.